# Android memory issue--VM won't let us allocate 2764800 bytes

Tags: android, out-of-memory, invocationtargetexception, inflate-exception

In my application i am using lots of layouts and lots of inflating in main.xml file. When i set this xml as a contentview application crashes. I have two splash screen before that. In those spash screens i used two images of >200kb size. From log it seems some memory leak issue may be. Here is my log:

```
09-06 03:26:14.749: E/GraphicsJNI(2212): VM won't let us allocate 2764800 bytes
09-06 03:26:14.788: D/AndroidRuntime(2212): Shutting down VM
09-06 03:26:14.788: W/dalvikvm(2212): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
09-06 03:26:14.788: I/EXCEPOTION(2212): Aise
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jukte.forgivenessapplication/com.jukte.forgivenessapplication.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #147: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #147: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at com.jukte.forgivenessapplication.Home.onCreate(Home.java:142)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     ... 11 more
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:133)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     ... 22 more
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:291)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:83)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:137)
09-06 03:26:14.952: E/AndroidRuntime(2212):     ... 26 more
```

I cant figure what is wrong...thanks for the help......

Comment: I would make sure you destroy all the splash screen assets and such manually, and notify the garbage collector. But without seeing code i cant tell more. What ever the size of the bitmap you are using... perhaps make it 16bit or 8bit png instead of 32bit?

Comment: Actually changing it 16bit or 8bit won't make any difference. It's just for file compression. As long as it's on memory as Bitmap, only Bitmap configuration and size of bitmap matters.

Comment: I was just about to post that he should be using different sizes of the image for different screen sizes. Normally larger screens have a larger heap. also you could get the heap size, and choose yourself which version of the image to load depending on heap size.

Comment: Depending on screen size for better heap is not really a good idea. Choosing pictures according to heap size seems logical. But how?

Comment: You can determine heap size using getMemoryClass() method of the ActivityManager class (   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  int memoryClass = activityManager.getMemoryClass();)

Answer (score 1):

The file size of the image (>200 KB in this case) has little to do with the amount of VM that will be required to load it.  Best way to determine the amount of memory required a priori use the height and width of the image, plus whether or not it has an alpha channel.

If you have an image with dimension of 400 x 800, alpha channel, and 8 bits per channel (ARGB_8888), it will require 400 x 800 x 4 bytes in VM to load the image.

Programmatically you can use, for example, a BitmapFactory.decodexxxx(xxxx, options) where options is set to decode only, then read the actual width and height of the image.  If the image is too large, you can use the same BitmapFactory method, with options set to scale the image.

Here's an example using an InputStream to load the image with

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(imageUri);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        inputStream.close();
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
```

Then based on the size of the image, you can use the same options to scale it as it loads:

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
        inputStream = context.getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(imageUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        inputStream.close();
```

Comment: It's >2MB, 200KB is just fine for a bitmap. My observation is that even 2MB for a bitmap is painful but loadable for devices has RAM about 512mb.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. I am using http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html this code for decoding the images in my splash screen. But still got the error. BTW i have a very complex layout in the next screen of splash. And i am not getting the error in splash screens i am getting error while inflating the xml file of the home screen.

Comment: Hi everybody i have solved the problem. The problem was all the images were very big in width and height. So i used decoding code of google to decode the images and used them.